# Dependency on VCOMP90.DLL in VS2008 Pro OpenMP project

Tags: visual-studio, openmp

I have a DLL project in VS 2008 Pro which uses OpenMP. I use /MT as 'code generation' option, because I want all my dependencies statically linked into my DLL, since I do not want to distribute many libraries to my clients - everything shall be included in this one DLL file. The problem is that my resulting DLL still depends on VCOMP90.DLL.

How can I get rid of this dependency?

Some information:

- /openmp is set in compiler options
- I statically link against vcomp.lib
- ## include  is set
- using multithreaded library (/MT)

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't think you'll be able to get rid of the DLL dependency - `vcomp.lib` is an import library for the VCOMP90.DLL - it's not a static library:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0h7x01y0.aspx

It doesn't look like a static lib is provided.

Comment: Note that this article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163717.aspx says that the Xbox 360 SDK supports static linking of the OpenMP.  I don't know if that's any help (maybe it can be hacked over to VS?).  Also, does MS provide source (I'm not at a machine with the OpenMP libs right now)?  If so, maybe a static lib can be compiled.  Either option sounds risky, though, if even workable.

Comment: The reason is OpenMP doesn't work well if loaded more than once. Read [this](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/openmp-static-library-deprecation-in-intelr-mkl-on-microsoft-windows).