# VS2012 and VCOMP110.dll

Tags: dependencies, visual-studio-2012

I swtiched a few days ago from VS1010 to VS2012 and the change gave me no trouble at all. Yesterday I took a compiled DLL to another machine and noticed it wouldn't work at all, not even load. Since the DLL runs bug free on the computer that I use to develop I thought it would be an unresolved dependency and I was right.

When building with VS2010 v110 toolset there's another additional dependency: VCOMP110.DLL . Is there a way to statically include this DLL at compilation time so I won't have to redistribute it along with the software?

Answer (score 1):

It should be Microsoft® C/C++ OpenMP Runtime

see http://systemexplorer.net/file-database/file/vcomp110-dll

But i didn't found a lib.

Comment: That's not what the OP was asking.

Comment: There is no static lib (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1634516/dependency-on-vcomp90-dll-in-vs2008-pro-openmp-project).
The only way is to disable OpenMP. Set Properties -> C/C++ -> Language -> Open MP Support to No.