# c / c++ dll missing dependencies without VS2012 installed ... with it its working fine

Tags: c++, c, dll, visual-studio-2012, dependencies

I made a c/c++ DLL compiled under /MT option.
It will be loaded by another program.
Now all this is working fine as long as I have the Visual Studio 2012 (Express or Professional, both is ok) installed (installed, no need to have it running): The external program will load the DLL without a problem.
So far if I go to another machine which does not have the Visual Studio 2012 installed, it won't load. I get the error "Missing dependencies ...".

I wonder: Which environment is VS2012 installing which is not available without it? How can I make this work without VS2012? Why does VCRedist* not install the environment nevessary?

Notes:
- running dumpbin /DEPENDENTS mydll.dll does not show any dependencies I would not have installed and available ... also it is running without any modification as soon as I installed VS2012 for a test
- I tested this on several systems, also installed all kinds of vcredist... versions to make sure that everything is ok. It wont start up as long as VS2012 is not installed (I did not try with VS2010 and such, most probably that would be fine as well)

Comment: Is the VS2012 runtime libraries redistributable package installed on the target system *for absolutely sure* ? It will be in the installed-programs list off control panel if it is.

Comment: Installing the redistributable package is the answer.

Comment: There is no error message that says "Missing dependencies ...".  Quoting the **exact** error message is essential to diagnose the problem.

Comment: There is no exact error, as the main program which calls the DLL is only printing "Missing dependencies." without giving details for bad luck. Do u mean the vcredist for visual studio 2012 SP1 like here http://www.microsoft.com/de-de/download/details.aspx?id=30679 ? If you mean this, I have it installed without luck. I have MS Vc++ 2005 Redist, 2008 Redist x64, Redist x86, 2010 x64 Redit, 2012 x86 and x64 ... without success. I see all this in system - installed software, so it is present.

Comment: Are you sure it's your DLL that is causing the problem and not something else that the external program tries to load? Have you run `dumpbin /DEPENDENTS` on it? Do you use .NET? Are you sure it's the release version and not the debug version? What about [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12226654/vs2012-and-vcomp110-dll?rq=1)?

Comment: Make sure you are not using any debug dlls or applications since the Microsoft debug runtime dlls are not redistributable.

Comment: Alright guys, you solved it. I really thought I checked many times I would not use any debug DLL. It turned out that the zeromq libzmq-..-gd...dll was the point of no return - the gd indicates debug version and my dll was using a function from there. Changing the includes and .libs to the libzmq...dll without the gd made the thing to load up correctly now. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I really thought I checked many times I would not use any debug DLL. So far I missed one! It turned out that the zeromq libzmq-..-gd...dll was the point of no return - the gd indicates debug version and my dll was using a function from there. Changing the includes and .libs to the libzmq...dll without the "gd" made the thing to load up correctly now. Of course all the comments about installing vcredist packages and so on were correctly as well but for me not the problem in this case (since I installed them). Thank you very much for pointing out that there must be some debug-compiled dll!